# Photostream/Photo import duplicates

Tags: photos.app, photo-stream

If I use photo stream and later plug my iPhone into the computer. Will I end up with a bunch of duplicates? Or will it import from my phone only any photos that weren't previously uploaded, for whatever reason, via photo stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No duplicates will be uploaded** to Photo Stream—only media that didn't get uploaded will be uploaded. This general rule also applies to photos transferred to other devices; the other device won't upload duplicates either.